# How to recive data from multiple Activities in Android?Stop Unexpectedly

Tags: android

I am developing sample a android app having three activities named Stationary, Books and Pens. I want to send data from Books and Pens activities to Stationary activity. In Stationary activity when I receive data from one activity either Books or Pens it works fine but when I receive data from both the activities my app "Stop Unexpectedly"

I have developed some code in this respect you can check it below.

in my Book activity am using the following code.

```
    // in Book Activity
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
     {
         if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
         {  



                if(myBookSelected)
                {   
                Intent intent = new Intent(Books.this,Stationary.class);
                intent.putExtra("bookSelected", books.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
                }

                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select books", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

          }

         return true;
     }
```

and in my Pens Activity am using the flowing code.

```
// in Pen Activity
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
     {
         if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
         {  



                if(myPenSelected)
                {   
                Intent intent = new Intent(Pens.this,Stationary.class);
                intent.putExtra("penSelected", pens.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
                }

                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select Pens", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

          }

         return true;
     }
```

To receive data in Stationary activity from the above two activities that is Books and Pens. I am using the following code.

```
// in Stationary Activity
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();


            if (extras != null)
            {   
                numberOfBooks = extras.getString("bookSelected");
                numberOfPens = extras.getString("penSelected");
            }
```

NOTE: When I receive data from one activity either Books or Pens it works fine but when I receive data from both the activities my app "Stop Unexpectedly"

Comment: you're doing it wrong. use startActivityForResult, and setResult in the books and pens acitivty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because when you try to pass a Intent from your BookActivity your "penSelected" will be null and in the other case "bookSelected" will be null. So obviously you will hit NullPointerException here.

A simply nasty solution will be to surround them in separate try catch blocks. Or you might have to send another data to identify from which Activity you are being passed and based on that get only the required field.

Say for example you come from PenActivty then you could get only "penSelected" and leave the other one and vice versa.

So what you have to understand here is, in neither of the cases your object "extras" wont be null , but only any one of the above key will be null. So you can't check for null there.

**EDIT**

i believe it is not true after all. You can check whether the Bundle Oject contains the key or not using the below code,

```
 if(getIntent().hasExtra("bookSelected"))
{
         // do your code.. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Each time a new activity starts, the previous activity is stopped, but the system preserves the activity in a stack (the "back stack")." [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to simply save your selections in a preference file. This way you don't have to worry about sending the data, about the activity order or if they are still alive or even after a phone reset you will still have your data saved. Please see the [tutorial about saving data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html), but basically is something like this:

```
...
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString(getString(R.string.pen_selected), penSelected);
editor.commit();
....
```

I think the reason why you receive a force close is because you can only receive data from the previous activity. If you want activity A sending *a* to activity C and activity B sending *b* to C then you should:

Step1) from activity A send *a* to activity B (and is started)

Step2) from activity B send *b* **and *a*** to activity C (and is started)

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Thanks dear and appreciate your effort.